# BABYLONJS : How to move the camera in front of a mesh

Tags: camera, move, mesh, babylonjs

It's my first post in StackOverFlow.
I'm asking for how can I put the camera in front of a mesh.

**Context :**

my projects is a museum, and when i click in to picture " mesh" , i need the camera get in front of the mesh , so that i can watch the picture.

**I tried :**

camera.postion = Mesh.position;

**Problem :**

the camera take the position of the mesh so i cannot see the picture , but i'm in the picture !

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can try to move the camera a bit away from the mesh position.

Something like that:

```
camera.position = mesh.position.add(new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 5));
camera.target = mesh.position
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the right solution ! 
Thank you for your answer ! i did tried before, but it doesn't worked properly !
**Solution !**

```
Picture.metadata={};

Picture.metadata.visitorPosition = new BABYLON.Vector3(x,y,z);

if (pickResult.hit){
if(!pickResult.pickedMesh.metadata){return;}
camera.position = pickResult.pickedMesh.metadata.visitorPosition;
camera.setTarget(pickResult.pickedMesh.position);}
```